# Can I Convert RGB > HSV the simple way?

Tags: python-3.x, colors

OK. I am creating a colour blindness simulator. I was developing a beta, where instead of a whole image, you would just insert the color's attributes in HSV/HSB.

```
h = input('Hue: ');
s = input('Saturation: ');
v = input('Value/Brightness: ');
```

But then, I need an algorithm or equation that can convert HSV/HSB into RGB. I've tried a lot of things, but most of the time I spent was looking at algorithms with operations python cannot use and trying to convert them into what python can understand. So, I just want a ***simple***, nice, algorithm, it's fine if you don't know how it works; but please. It would also be nice if I could convert RGB > HSV, and both without any imports. Also, it doesn't matter if you have to replace HSV into HSL.

Comment: Wikipedia has them. You should just check what type of data do you have (full range, or limited range, as in many video), and e.v. colour space. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Color_conversion_formulae

Comment: No. It very simple. 3 formulas. In any case, the formula are there. You cannot simplify them further, without changing the meaning of the numbers, and so not more useful.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, I tried to take this formula and turn it into python, but for some reason, when I enter Hue as 0, Saturation as 100, and Value as 100, I get [1.0,1.0,0]. Do you have any python solutions? Merry Christmas (if you celebrate it).

Comment: Oh wait; I was supposed to enter h=0, s=1, and v=1. Thank you. Also, on github https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/colorsys.py, I found a python solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour) implements *Machado, Oliveira and Fernandes (2009)* Colour Vision Deficiency (CVD) model:

```py
H = 0 # input('Hue: ')
S = 0.95 # input('Saturation: ')
V = 0.75 # input('Value/Brightness: ')
deficiency = 'Protanomaly' # input('Deficiency (Protanomaly, Deuteranomaly, Tritanomaly)')
severity = 0.75 # input('Severity [0, 1]')

# Assuming linear H, S, V input.
HSV = [H, S, V]

RGB = colour.cctf_decoding(colour.HSV_to_RGB(HSV))
M_a = colour.blindness.matrix_cvd_Machado2009(deficiency, severity)
RGB_a = colour.utilities.vector_dot(M_a, RGB)

colour.plotting.plot_multi_colour_swatches(colour.cctf_encoding([RGB, RGB_a]));
```

[image: CVD Swatches]

For a colour wheel:

```py
def colour_wheel(samples=512, clip_circle=True, method='Colour'):
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(
        np.linspace(-1, 1, samples), np.linspace(-1, 1, samples))

    S = np.sqrt(xx ** 2 + yy ** 2)    
    H = (np.arctan2(xx, yy) + np.pi) / (np.pi * 2)

    HSV = colour.utilities.tstack([H, S, np.ones(H.shape)])
    RGB = colour.HSV_to_RGB(HSV)

    if clip_circle == True:
        RGB[S > 1] = 0

    if method.lower()== 'nuke':
        RGB = colour.utilities.orient(RGB, 'Flip')
        RGB = colour.utilities.orient(RGB, '90 CW')

    return RGB


colour.plotting.plot_image(colour.cctf_encoding(
    colour_wheel()));

colour.plotting.plot_image(colour.cctf_encoding(
    colour.utilities.vector_dot(M_a, colour_wheel())));
```

[image: Colour Wheel]
[image: Colour Wheel - CVD]

Comment: Please, may you give me a formula? Also, it would be nice if there was no imports, thank you.

Comment: The above conversions require a significant amount of spectral computations, there is no such a thing as a formula for Machado, Oliveira and Fernandes (2009) CVD model.

Comment: A formula as I mean one to convert RGB to HSV without any imports, if the Machado, Oliveira and Fernandes (2009) CVD model includes one or publishes their code. I'm definitely fine on the colorblindness part, thank you. In the already-included github link, I couldn't find any code with a formula that converts RGB to HSV.

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/develop/colour/models/rgb/cylindrical.py